# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot get python matplotlib working, it keep says require dateutil

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I import matplotlib in python, it keeps saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

stats after typing

> pip freeze

in command line is:

```
...
python-dateutil==2.2
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
pytz==2014.7
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.2.1
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
six==1.7.3
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
ssh-import-id==3.21
system-service==0.1.6
tornado==4.0.1
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.7.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

Comment: how did you install matplotlib?  there is a package in the ubuntu package manager called python-matplotlib that is probably the easiest option.

Comment: I suspect something is crossed in your install/python paths as that exception is raised when  `import dateutil` fails.  What do you get if you try `import dateutil` from the prompt?  I wonder if the `dateutil` installation is messed up and mpl is snarfing a possibly more useful import error message...

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, I used 'sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib' to install matplotlib

Comment: @tcaswell Hi, yes this error is from prompt after I type 'import matplotlib' manually

Comment: please re-read my comment, I want to know if `import dateutil` works.